# Doesn't JavaScript Minification hurt open source?

Tags: javascript, open-source, minify

There's an awful lot on the web these days about how important it is to minify your JavaScript. Speed is all that matters.

But doesn't minification work against the openness of Open Source?

One of the great things about JS (as opposed to flash and the back-end) is that the source code is right there, available to be viewed by other developers who come along and think "Hey, that looks good, I wonder how they did that". The JS source code is available for everyone to see, and so developers can learn from it, adapt it, and use similar JS on their own projects.

Minifying JS makes it unreadable. It stops the external developer from being able to read the code, and so cancels out horizontal sharing and learning.

Obviously there will be some who wish to minify their JS for the express purpose of attempting to hold on to their intellectual property. It's always a shame when people undermine the creativity of the open-source community, but it's somewhat understandable, and certainly not going to stop.

But for the rest of us developers - the people who use open-source every day of our lives - JS minification gets in our way. It makes us unable to take advantage of the openness of the web. It closes down the possibility of creative sharing.

I'm all about some things being minified - libraries, plugins, etc (and maybe when serving JS to mobile). But for the custom-built code that makes your individual website individual, minifying your code is really not that necessary. It may save a few ms of download time, but keeping it open won't change that much. Most of the sites on the web probably have less than 20KB of custom JS code, and the benefit of minifying that really is minimal. Do a few ms really compare with the benefit of keeping JS code open, readable and available for others?

For sites with more JS, maybe we could start to develop an open-source-based standard, so that developers can type in a slightly different URL in order to be served the unminified code. If the minified code is at domain.com/script.min.js, let's make the unminified always available at domain.com/script.js or /script.full.js. Or are there other suggestions?

I can't really find anything else on the web talking about this issue. Everything is on the other side - pushing minification. And that alarms me. It makes me think that, as developers, we've allowed ourselves to sink into an unquestioned ideology of speed, regardless of other factors. And probably, because of the nature of ideology, some of you reading this will immediately want to dismiss it and argue against it. But think just a little bit longer -  is the tiny speed benefit really worth the loss of open-source creativity? I don't believe it is.

So I guess my question is, where's the debate about open-source JavaScripting?

Comment: On the same note, is coding in JavaScript at all a good idea for the long-term development of our industry, products and community? It's a necessary evil at the moment, but I'd rather put my ideological efforts into getting rid of JavaScript as a coding language altogether.

Comment: @sinelaw LOL & wtf? True about flash, but JavaScript? You know there's other browsers out there beside IE, right? :)

Comment: It *alarms* you because me build processes include JS minification by default, and you want my app's custom code?

Comment: @lwburk / tybro0103: because JavaScript has [too many pitfalls](http://garabedyan.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/crockford-javascripts-bad-and-good-parts/). It's a point you can argue, but my opinion is that JavaScript is not a language you should be coding with (evidence that I'm not alone, the increasing popularity of projects such as GWT). I consider it "assembly language for browsers".

Comment: @DaveNewton it alarms me because of the single-mindedness of the ideology. I can understand people wanting to protect your custom code - you can do so if you wish. But for open-source-minded programmers, having the source code available can be very helpful.

Comment: @thugsb ... You ascribe malice to something that IMO you shouldn't (a) be concerned about at all, and (b) don't really have any right to be indignant about. YMMV; carry on.

Comment: @DaveNewton Malice? I'm not ascribing malice. I'm advocating openness and the freedom to learn. How is that malice?

Comment: @thugsb You were talking about an "intent to protect IP". IMO, you consider that malicious, because impedes *your* ability to look at an app's custom code. What if that isn't the intent? Why don't you want the rest of my app's code? If a site/dev doesn't release their custom JS as an open source library, you don't have a leg to stand on other than "I'd like to see that code in a way I find acceptable". That's fine, but oh well.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's not really my ability I'm worried about - there are a lot of programmers who learn through copy-and-paste, and that's a valuable and viable way to learn. By having open and readable JS, the learning bar is lowered. Not everyone can afford university education (I can, I have an MA) or even a comp-sci course, and lowering the entry bar can help people to get jobs and to expand their knowledge. The comp-sci's will still get the better jobs. I'm not trying to force people to use open source. I'm trying to encourage those who do to keep their source code readable and available.

Comment: @thugsb But you're not talking about open-source, you're talking about an app's custom JS code. What's FOSS about that? Nothing, unless they declare it as such.

Comment: @thugsb - *"I'm advocating openness and the freedom to learn."* Yes, you certainly are advocating *something*. This is not so much a question as an Op-Ed piece. Hence, it's not appropriate for SO. Start a blog.

Comment: And if they do declare it as FOSS, then it would be useful to provide non-minified JS. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure most — if not all — open source JavaScript libraries that offer minified versions also offer the original sources for developers to work on. It's just like how open source programs that distribute compiled binaries for general use also distribute their original sources to the public.

If you're referring to custom scripts made on a per-project basis specifically for a certain project, those scripts are not open source by default unless the author specifically cites/includes a FOSS license notice. To that end, I'm not obliged to provide an unminified version of my custom code unless I *intend* to distribute it freely *and* license it as such.

Comment: +1 comparison to compiled code

Comment: I'm not talking about libraries and plugins though. You'll notice that I said I support minifying libraries and plugins. It's the custom code that needs a non-minified version, and that code isn't available unless you (as a developer) provide it.

Comment: @thugsb: I updated my answer. It's not open source unless the author says it is.

Comment: @thugsb: And if your next question is why don't more people open source their scripts, well, I guess not everyone likes to share — companies included (and particularly selfish).

Comment: I'm just saying that for those who do want their source to be open, it would be good to provide an open/readable version. I'm not saying everyone needs to make their code open. Though I would encourage it.

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript is meant to be open source then you will also be able to find the un-minified version. For example, jQuery:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

There are both "minified" and "uncompressed" files for download.

If you find a javascript file which claims to be open source and does not have the uncompressed file available, then a mistake has been made.

Comment: I'm not talking about libraries and plugins. I know that they provide unminified versions. I'm talking about providing unminified versions of the custom code that is built for each and every website. That code doesn't need to be minified. It would be better if it were open.

Comment: Same goes for a website... if it's really open source than the developer should make available un-minified js for site.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no debate; I haven't seen many (any?) FOSS JS libs that don't have a non-minified version.

Even if there was, FOSS doesn't mean *readable*--even non-minified code can be completely illegible.

Comment: +1 "non-minified code can be completely illegible" VERY TRUE! :)

Comment: Shared source code must be readable, see http://www.linfo.org/source_code.html

Comment: @AnthonyEbert  You've missed the joke *entirely*. Take, for example, an open source Braimfuck application. Get it now?

Answer (score 1):

> One of the great things about JS (as opposed to flash and the
>   back-end) is that the source code is right there, available to be
>   viewed by other developers who come along and think "Hey, that looks
>   good, I wonder how they did that".

I don't think we really want to encourage the practice of learning Javascript from the source of websites stumbled upon randomly. If you want to learn Javascript, it's much better to learn from an actual open source project that's been **documented, tested and written with care**.

99% of the time if I don't open-source a piece of JS, it's not because of intellectual property concerns. It's because it's a quick hack - not suitable for community consumption

> Most of the sites on the web probably have less than 20KB of custom JS
>   code, and the benefit of minifying that really is minimal.

Whether or not the saving is 2kb (which still makes a difference, incidentally) or 2mb, minification is a best practice, and should be instilled in developers from the get-go.

Comment: But why is it best practice? Just to feel good about your YSlow performance? What I'm arguing is that maybe it isn't ALWAYS best practice. And even if the 2kb does matter (hardly), then you should also provide a non-minimized version. Even if it's a hack, it's used for reason, and someone else may need to duplicate that same hack.

Comment: It's best practice because a more responsive page is always better. Again, I would argue that copying a hack from a website you've stumbled upon is a bad idea and going to cost you time in the long run - and as another poster mentioned, undocumented, thrown-together code is often just as unreadable as minified code.